# iframes - Change parent's URL without specifying the domain name

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, electron, parent

So, my code technically works. The iframe does change the parent's URL. Problem is, the parent is an Electron Application and not a real website. So I need to change its URL like this: `../page/index.html` and not like this: `http://website.com/page/index.html`. Let's say the URL address the `<iframe>` is loading is `www.iframe.com/cake/index.html`. When the code down below occurs, it changes the parent's URL to `www.iframe.com/page/index.html`. That URL does not even exist and even if it did, it's not what I wanted to do.

```
var status = document.getElementById("status").innerHTML;
if (status === "True") {
top.window.location.href='../page/index.html';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by just using `window.postMessage();`
I guess that's the best method to work with iframes.